# Should I keep old or expired SSL crt, cabundle and key files

Tags: tls, certificates

Is there a standard or best practice as far as retaining old or expired SSL crt, cabundle and key files for your domains?

Comment: The key file allows decryption of recorded traffic for connections that used RSA key exchange (i.e. all cipher suites that don't say DHE or ECDHE), so don't let it get stolen. I destroy mine when rotating the cert, but maybe someone has a better answer.

Comment: Yes, destroy it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's expired so it's no good for daily use. But it might be able to decrypt previous data. If you don't plan on recovering that, destroy the damn thing. In linux, this can be done with the `shred` command.